Google Sheets Combine two queries into one
I have a query in Google sheets as follows:
=Query('Final Tracker'!B:G, "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col4, Col6 Where Col3='Credit Card payment' OR Col6='Credit Card'", 0)

It works as intended, that is to say that all returned rows are sorted in the order specified:
Example data from Final Tracker:



Column B (Date)
Column C (Description)
Column D (Category)
Column E (Income)
Column F (Expenses)
Column G (Account Type)




01-04-2024
Etsy
Personal
$42.73

Checking


01-04-2024
Walmart
Personal

$42.73
Credit Card


05-04-2024
payment
Credit Card payment

$25.00
Checking



Result from the query:



Column B (Date)
Column C (Description)
Column D (Category)
Column E (Income)
Column F (Expenses)
Column G (Account Type)




01-04-2024
Walmart
Personal
$42.73

Credit Card


05-04-2024
payment
Credit Card payment
$25.00

Checking



but I need to modify the query so that it changes the sort order of the columns based on which column is returning the result:
If Col3 = "Credit Card payment" the sort order should be Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col4, Col6 
but if Col6 = "Credit Card" the sort order should be Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6

Expected output:



Column B (Date)
Column C (Description)
Column D (Category)
Column E (Income)
Column F (Expenses)
Column G (Account Type)




01-04-2024
Walmart
Personal

$42.73
Credit Card


05-04-2024
payment
Credit Card payment
$25.00

Checking



Col3 will never equal "Credit Card payment" if Col6 = "Credit Card".
How do I modify the query to adapt the different sort orders?

I don't see how you specified the order as you wrote "It works as intended..."

share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

@cyberbrain "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col4, Col6

So with "sort order" you mean the order of the columns, not the sorting of the rows?

Use byrow(), if() and choosecols(), like this:
=let( 
  data, query('Final Tracker'!B:G, "where Col3 = 'Credit Card payment' or Col6 = 'Credit Card'", 0), 
  byrow(data, lambda(row, if( 
    choosecols(row, 3) = "Credit Card payment", 
    choosecols(row, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6), 
    row 
  ))) 
)

See
let(),
byrow()
and
choosecols().

It says Function CHOOSECOLS parameter 2 value is 3. Valid values are between -1 and 1 inclusive.

That indicates that the query() is erroring out. Test the query portion of the formula in a cell of its own to confirm that it works correctly.

The formula in the answer does not insert an additional row when the data looks like what's given in the question.

You can just STACK up the queries:
=LET(
  data,'Final Tracker'!B2:G,  
  VSTACK(
    QUERY(data, "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col4, Col6 Where Col3='Credit Card payment'", 0),
    QUERY(data, "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 Where Col6='Credit Card'", 0)
  )
)

SORT by Col1 if needed post stacking.

Where would one put the sort? When I try it errors out saying SORT expects all arguments after position 1 to be in pairs.

@Sweepster =SORT(the above formula without =,1,0) Review SORT documentation. The error means you're missing one of the arguments of SORT.

Nice, thank you. Everything works as expected except it inserts an additional row with a blank date and #N/A in all the other columns, Is there a way to prevent that?

Is there a  blank in between rows somewhere? Maybe try adding a not null clause (like Where Col3='Credit Card payment' and Col1 is not null) in all queries. If that doesn't work, please ask a new question with [mcve]

comma appending the second query is likely to add an extra erroneous row at the end of ouput
